# Find first elements from list of list of Integer java

Tags: java, list, arraylist, time-complexity

I am looking for better solution (time and complexity wise) for the below problem:

Given List of List of Integers. First print all first elements, then all second elements and so on.

Example: `{{1,2,3}, {5,4,6}}` prints `1,5,2,4,3,6`

Solution 1: I can iterate over list of lists using two for loop but with that time complexity will increase to `O(n^2)`.  Is there a better way to achieve above result using `O(n)`?

Comment: ok... i see... "prints 1,5,2,4,3,6" doesn't look as "first elements from list" though...

Comment: I think what the OP wants is the first number of each list, then the second number of each list and then the third number and so on

Comment: That's why they would need two loops

Comment: @Roland Yes, actually you're right. In which case, I think I see the visual pattern but the problem is incorrectly described.

Comment: Is it safe to assume that all lists have the same number of items?

Comment: @lupz good question

Comment: It cant be achieve in O(N) complexity as all elements need to be printed

Comment: @Chintan could you update your question to "Given List of List of Integers. Print all first elements. Then all second elements. And so on... Until all elements are printed." **if this was your intention**?

Comment: well, it depends from what you mean by `n`, if `n` is number of all elements in all lists then you solution is actually most probably `O(n)`, if you mean `n` is just number of lists, then obviously answer is no, because number of elements in the lists can be mush higher then number of lists.

Comment: I still dont get what is the question, or purpose of solution I mean.. Please clarify what are you trying to achieve, thanks in advance, also topic update should be fine.

Comment: You are looking for a zip function imlementation

Comment: updated questions as suggested by @david

Comment: @Chintan how do you define `n`? is it number of all elements in all lists?

Comment: @RuslanAkhundov i think you are right. There are ```N``` elements on each inner list. The number of inner lists is ```C```. When ```N``` is increased by 1 there are ```C``` operations more to do. When ```C``` increases there are ```N``` operations more to do. The complexity is dominated by the bigger one of both, which should reduce to some kind of O(n). There is nothing funky going on here as in bubble sort or so. I is just going through n elements.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: **No**.

Long answer: Say you wanted to do it in one loop. If all the inner lists are of the same length, **and** if you have fast random-access to list elements (e.g. an array list), you can calculate the position of the next element. Pseudo-Java-Code:

```
int totalElements = outerListSize * innerListSize;
for(int targetPos = 0; targetPos < totalElements; targetPos++) {
    //For the outer list, choose the next index until reaching
    //the end, then roll over
    int outerIndex = targetPos % outerListSize;
    //For the inner lists, choose 0 until the outer lists roll
    //over, then 1, ...
    int innerIndex = targetPos / outerListSize;

    targetList.add(targetPos, outerList.get(outerIndex).get(innerIndex));
}
```

But this will not save you anything, because now you have a single loop that runs from 0 to n*n - You still have O(n2)

Answer (score 1):

Well, everything depends from what you mean by `n`.

Usually `n` is the size of input, in your case size of input is number of all elements in all lists(sum of all list sizes), then there is linear solution that takes `O(n)`, because you visit each element only once.
Here is my implementation, however there can be multiple ways to do this, I assume your solution, which you claim takes `O(n^2)` time actually also linear and takes `O(n)`.

```
    List<List<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));
    list.add(Arrays.asList(5, 4, 6));

    Map<Integer, List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (List<Integer> integers : list) {
        for (int i = 0; i < integers.size(); i++) {
            map.computeIfAbsent(i, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(integers.get(i));
        }
    }

    int i = 0;
    while (map.containsKey(i)) {
        for (Integer value : map.get(i)) {
            System.out.print(value + ", ");
        }
        ++i;
    }
```

However, if I am wrong and you define `n` as number of lists, then we have a problem, as list size is independent form number of lists. So lets assume in worst case one of your internal lists has size `m`, then overall complexity is `O(nm)`.And you obviously can't do faster that this, because you have overall `O(nm)` elements, and you need to visit each element at list ones to print it.

I don't think you can estimate your algorithm complexity defining `n` as a number of lists, without defining worst case number of elements per list.